# Why there is no cursor adapter for RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I found a working cursorAdapter for RecyclerView gist. It works similarly as for listView. But I can't understand why there is no default cursor adapter. It is bad practice using cursor adapter and need manually get data from db convert to list of objects and then use it? Or what explanation for this?

Comment: @DougStevenson for what i need try google search? I said that I found cursorAdapter for RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't understand why there is no default cursor adapter

Google elected not to create any concrete adapters for specific types of data collections.

You are certainly welcome to use a `Cursor` as the model data for a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Just bear in mind that a `Cursor` treats the position as internal state. Make sure that your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` pulls the data out of the `Cursor` and uses it, rather than holding onto the `Cursor` itself and assuming that it will always automatically be pointing to the correct row.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList) demonstrates a `RecyclerView` backed by a `Cursor`, in this case a `Cursor` obtained from querying the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`.